# 2 circuits in a double gang box

Tags: wiring

Can you have two different circuits (separate) in a double gang box--one for a light and the other for a receptacle in a bathroom or anywhere in your house?

Answer (score 2):

No problem.   Two circuits can share a box, and even serve different switches or outlets in the same box. Be careful to keep hots and neutrals separate.

For instance a household member really likes running the hair dryer and curler at the same time.  Nothing stops you from running dual 12/2 to the bathroom receptacle, splitting hot and neutral tabs, and serving each socket from a dedicated GFCI breaker.

You could even do that with different main services, e.g. The above but with one side served with mains power, the other from a separately derived PV or generator system.  However you would need to distinguish each system with different wire markings or colors.  This is why gray is an allowed neutral color.

Comment: You mentioned that two circuits can share even outlet and if so I thought that tandem wiring wasn't acceptable? In one of my bedroom (4 duplex receptacles-14 gauge) are connected to a light switch with 2 different circuit breakers with all of receptacles split. Can I leave this as is or can I take one of the circuit breakers on the switch and pigtail it to the bottom or top of the switch thus eliminating a tandem wiring setup and everything would be on one circuit? No I haven't checked each receptacle to see if they are using different circuit wires. Only the switch is using 2 different circut

Comment: As long as every neutral stays with its companion hot, you can do what you want.  Proof of the pudding is temporarily fitting a GFCI breaker and it doesn't trip if you try a lamp in every outlet.